# Does Hovertool/tooltip work with pandas df or only with ColumnDataSource

Tags: bokeh, pandas-bokeh

Pretty new to Bokeh. Plotting a barplot (after importing pandas_bokey) works well.
But... I want to change the hoover tooltips.
Question: should hoover tooltip work with a pandas df in Bokeh or must ColumnDataSource be used?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option in `pandas_bokeh` to modify the HoverTool is passing a custom string to `hovertool_string`.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_bokeh

from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
df.plot_bokeh.bar(hovertool_string=r"""At index @{__x__values}: a is @{a} and b is @{b}""")
```

| **default output** | **modified tooltop** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: default tooltip] | [image: modified tooltip] |

To see a more complex example check the 2. example [in the line plot documentation](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh#basic-lineplot)

**Comment**

Because your question is very open, I am not sure if the answer is satisfying. Please provide some Minimal Working Example and some example data in future.

Comment: thank you. Sorry for late reaction. Your answer helps a lot. cheers.